# apply function ifelse summing up two columns

Tags: r, function, sum, apply

I would like to find a solution for the following problem, hope someone can help me. 
I have a dataframe with over 2000 columns and I need just two of them. First I need to check if the sums (df$values1 + df$values2.) of the two columns are than 15. 
Now I would like to have a result column:
If yes: 15
If no: sum up the values of the first to the second column, so that df$values1 + df$values2.

I tried to get an result with the following, but it doesn't work:

```
df$result <- apply(df[which(colnames(df)=="values1")],2, 
    function(x) {ifelse(df[which(colnames(df)=="values2")]+x >= 15, 15, df[which(colnames(df) == "values2")] + x)
    }
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's a missing word in your description just before "than"  which could be one of either "less"  or "greater". Perhaps also could have used (assuming the word was "greater"):  `with(df,  ifelse( values1 +values2 > 15, 15, values1+values2)`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly:

```
df$sumOfValues = pmin(df$values1 + df$values2, 15)
```

Comment: Agree that is probably the way to go and thatt the question is ambiguous, but I think the likely correct function would be `pmax`.

Comment: `pmax` would act like a lower bound, the `+ x >= 15` part of the question makes me suspect they seek an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

[From now on, make sure that you post reproducible questions if you would like to get any help from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

First of all, let's look at your code.

```
df$result <-
  apply(df[which(colnames(df) == "values1")], 2, function(x) {
    ifelse(df[which(colnames(df) == "values2")] + x >= 15,
           15,
           df[which(colnames(df) ==
                      "values2")] + x)
  })
```

> Your code "says":  for each column called values1 in df  if any value
>   in `values2` in `df` `+` the value in `values1` is equal or greater
>   than `15`, assign the value `15`, else assign `values2` + the values
>   in `values1`.

Basically, you are replacing a single number with a vector, hence you are returning a list.

Tips:

1) Don't refer to your columns by using `which`. Instead, directly subset your data, either by using `df[,1]` or similar or by `df$values1`.

2) Don't use `apply` when applying a function on 1-dimensional data.

Solutions, either the example written by **kgolyaev** above or, if you would like to use `ifelse` you could go by:

```
ifelse(df$values1 + df$values2 >= 15,
       15, df$values1 + df$values2)
```